# Get day of the week from stored datetime

Tags: sql

I've used this

```
select datename(weekday,getdate())
```

to give me today's date, but if I use

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,dob()) from myTable
```

where dob is my stored field that I want to get the day or the week for, it gives me an error.  Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your column have parentheses in it? I am guessing it doesn't so you just use the column name:

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,dob) 
from myTable
```

see a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0dc1/1) with an example

Comment: ah.  I was acting as if it were a function.  Thanks, will accept when it lets me.

Comment: no problem, we have all done stuff like that. :)  Sometimes it takes another set of eyes.